# Layout_alignParentRight and others aren't working

Tags: android

I'm simply trying to do the first app-making lesson on Udacity with making a birthday card app. It asks me to put "**From yourName**" on the birthday card to the bottom right. I tried using `android:layout_alignParentRight` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and nothing has changed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Happy Birthday friendName!"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="From yourName!"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/androidparty" />
```

Comment: the `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_alignParentRight` atttribute used when parent layout is **`RelativeLayout`** the both attribute not work with `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: @NileshRathod is right and for `ConstraintLayout` use like this **`app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"`**.  follow link : **[Constraint Layout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)**

Comment: Kindly do some research before posting question

Comment: @NileshRathod Thank you how can I get rid of the constraint layout?

Comment: @AlinaS check my below answer   https://stackoverflow.com/a/53940434/7666442 i have posted a sample code

Comment: @NileshRathod Thank you so much I was able to fix it!!!

Comment: @AlinaS Glad to have been of help! Feel free to [accept my answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234) if you feel it was useful to you. :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it lacks any previous research.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `android:layout_alignParentRight` and `android:layout_alignParentBottom` then

Use `RelativeLayout` as **root layout**

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Happy Birthday friendName!"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="From yourName!"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/androidparty" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_alignParentRight` attributes used when parent layout is **`RelativeLayout`** the both attribute not work with `ConstraintLayout`

Just change your root layout to **`RelativeLayout`** it will work

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Happy Birthday friendName!"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="From yourName!"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/androidparty" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`android:layout_alignParentRight` or `android:layout_alignParentBottom` works with RelativeLayout

For Constraint layout you have to use

```
app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
```